# Java: Automatic 'throws' declaration: is it, and if so, what is its value?

Tags: java, function, exception

Take any method for example. `public static void main(String[] args)` is as good as any other. If I have code therewithin that will throw, for example, a `NullPointerException`, why don't I have to declare that my method throws this?

Is assumption that without definition, all methods will throw some specific predefined exceptions, correct? If so, what are they?

To clarify, I am not seeking help with broken code, but asking a question about how Java itself works.

Comment: If your code is throwing NullPointerException, then it's the problem of your code. It should have been taken care by you. Also there is more potential for NullPointerException. If it would be a Checked Exception, your code will be full of try-catch block :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime exceptions represent problems that are the result of a programming problem, and as such, the API client code cannot reasonably be expected to recover from them or to handle them in any way. Such problems include arithmetic exceptions, such as dividing by zero; pointer exceptions, such as trying to access an object through a null reference; and indexing exceptions, such as attempting to access an array element through an index that is too large or too small.

Runtime exceptions can occur anywhere in a program, and in a typical one they can be very numerous. Having to add runtime exceptions in every method declaration would reduce a program's clarity. Thus, the compiler does not require that you catch or specify runtime exceptions (although you can).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two main sets of `Exception`. One is the ones who inherits `RuntimeException`. You need not define it (as `void f() throws SomeException`). These are called *unchecked exception*.

For the other ones you have to. They are called *checked exception*.

For more details, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Java has checked and unchecked exceptions. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html):

> The unchecked exception classes are the run-time exception classes and the error classes.
>
> The checked exception classes are all exception classes other than the unchecked exception classes. That is, the checked exception classes are all subclasses of Throwable other than RuntimeException and its subclasses and Error and its subclasses.

`NullPointerException` is an example of an unchecked exception. This means that you are not forced to catch it or add the `throws NullPointerException` for every method that has a chance of throwing it.

`FileNotFoundException` is a checked exception. So if you use a `FileInputStream`, which throws a `FileNotFoundException`, you need to either surround it with a try-catch block or declare that the method it is in throws a `FileNotFoundException`.